# Jquery how to trigger HadClass in Form

Tags: javascript, jquery

A newbie would like to ask for a little help.

In this part

[image]

I would like to trigger a script to display the hidden element. Currently, the element is display: none;

This is the jquery.

```
<script>
  if($('#pw').hasClass('current')) {
    $('.site-terms').css('display', 'block');
  };
</script>
```

This is a 5step form. I wanted to display the site terms on the last step of the form.

Please help me with this situation. Appreciate all of your help!

Comment: Are you running the script when DOM is loaded? in document ready function?

Comment: could you paste the html code like you did the javascript? or at least take a screenshot from an ide? it would help a lot.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar no. the DOM is already loaded. This is a 5 step form. I just wanted to display the hidden element on the last step (5th step).

Comment: 5step form with the same id? id need to be unique

Comment: @katzenhut here it is https://jsfiddle.net/qLrgbak6/

Comment: you must check the class in your `nextButton` function

Comment: @Sysix wow you're amazing!! thank you very much! it fixed now when I trigger the next button!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When do you want to trigger that script?

You'll need to do that with an event handler:

```
$('someElement').on('click', function() {
  // trigger script here
});
```

You can read more about events in jQuery here: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: 1st step: gender after you provide values, it slides, so on and so forth until in 5th step (after the 4th step slided), i wanted to display block the hidden element. Check my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qLrgbak6/

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i've fixed my concern using your code and the above comment. Thank you!! Appreciated it a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help. You can experiment with the `blur`, `input` and `change` events to get the effect you are looking for.

Comment: Also, if you think my answer is correct, you can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

You would need an event handler on you element. There a a few handlers that you can choose from here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_events.asp.

Personally I would trigger the element on click or on focus so that it could also work as someone presses tab through the field.

```
$('someElement').on('click', function() {
//enter code here
}).on('focus', function() {
//enter code here
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your help! i've fixed my concern after i've used your code! appreciated it a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can even use the following event handler

```
$('#password').on('blur', function(){
   // put your code to show site terms
})
```

This event will be triggered when you move your focus from the last input field. i.e when you have completed the last step.

Hope this helps.